# Display multiple rows in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have  query where I fetch the content of about 5 rows each with different content, but i dont now to display them individually in my views.

When I pass the the `query->result()` from my model back to my controller as `$query`, and then load a view with the `$query` data, I don't know how to echo out the e.g. content field of row 1.

I only know how to do this: `foreach($query as $row) { echo $row->content; }`

But this doesn't allow me to select what row content data (out of the 5 retrieved) I wanna `echo` out.

Could someone please explain how this is done?

Answer (score 4):

The CodeIgniter documentation includes a section titled [Generating Query Results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) which has some examples of what you are looking for.

Here's an (obviously contrived) example:

*model:*

```
class Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_data()
    {
        return $this->db->query('...');
    }
}
```

*controller:*

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['query_result'] = $this->model->get_data();
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

*view:*

```
<?php foreach ($query_result->result() as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row->field_1; ?>
    <?php echo $row->field_2; ?>
    <?php // and so on... ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: as @birderic example said, when you pass a variable to a view, the "top" of the array get's sliced off so to speak. So always put it in an array, example: $data['post_data'] = $this->db->get('');

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){   
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('table');
   $this->db->where(array('batch_id'=>$batchid,'class_id'=>$classid));
   $this->db->where(array('batch_id'=>$batchid,'class_id'=>$classid));
   $query=$this->db->get();
   for($i=1;$i<=$query->num_rows();++$i){
      $data[$i]['task'] = $query->row($i)->task;
      $data[$i]['subject_id'] = $query->row($i)->subject_id;
      $data[$i]['postdate'] = $query->row($i)->postdate;
      $data[$i]['cdate'] = $query->row($i)->cdate;
   }
}
```